# How to save the "repeating" rebase step?

Tags: git

I have learning to use git for my R programming, and I have come to the following issue:

most of the time I need to write branches, as the same dataset may give different analysis, tables, and charts, like this one, I branched D into D1 and E.

```
A---B---C---D---E
             \
             D1
```

when something is wrong in B, I'll checkout the B, recode it and then commit it again, say it is now B1

```
A---B---C---D---E
     \       \
      B1      D1
```

In order for the C, D, D1, E to start from B1, like the one below, I need to do LOTS of `rebase`

```
A---B---B1---C---D---E
                  \
                   D1

git rebase B1 C
git rebase C D
git rebase D D1
git rebase D E
```

I think this is quite stupid to do so, being a newer in git, can anyone enlighten me so that I don't need to hit `rebase` all the time?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if it will work precisely in your case, but saving and re-applying resolution merge conflicts are done through **[git rerere](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-rerere.html)**.
(See [rerere your boat](http://progit.org/2010/03/08/rerere.html) or [Fun with rerere](http://gitster.livejournal.com/41795.html))

That means: you will still have lots of merge to do, but most of them will be automatically resolved, through previous merge resolutions recorded with `rerere`.

Answer (score 1):

Rebasing rewrites history.  You would normally avoid that on a shared repository.  When a public project makes a change in a "project branch" like B1, the normal way to roll it forward would be to merge it onto trunk, producing `...---C---D---E---E+B1` and then you'd only rebase your project branch D1 onto your new trunk.  If D1 is more of a "release branch" then you'd also merge B1 there to avoid picking up the unwanted E.

(As a side note, even if you are rebasing, you would only need to rebase each branch onto B1, not every individual revision)

Comment: do you mean I only need to do `git rebase B1 D1` and `git rebase B1 E`?

Comment: Right, you don't have to "ripple" the change yourself.  A rebase will export all non-common commits of the two branches (eg D1, D, C) with `format-patch` and then reapply them with `am` to your target, B1.

Answer (score 1):

I do not see a point of rebasing, just add your fix on top of master branch and then cherry-pick it into D.

```
A---B---C---D---E
             \
             D1

A---B---C---D---E---B1
             \
             D1

A---B---C---D---E---B1
             \
             D1--B1
```

It will preserve the history as well, as [Ben](https://stackoverflow.com/users/479989/ben-jackson) pointed out, it is important if many people work on the same repo.

Comment: What if `C`, `D`, `E`, and `D1` need `B1` to work properly? (Your cherry-picking has also created a duplicate commit.)

Comment: agree with Jefromi, actually B1, or the early part of the trunk belongs to the data manipulation part, I need to recode/regroup the data using B1, then throw it to D1 and E for calculation of rates, so I need to be "back in time" and fix B before moving on to D1 and E

Comment: Then use merge instead of cherry-picking. Duplicate commit is a common thing on large projects, it is the only way to apply a single critical patch from master to the stable branch really.